Load php functions only once per session
May be this a stupid question as I am not a coder, just learning php, and started to build my very first php website for study, and I am curious how this works.
So here is my question:
I have a head.php file containing functions that are needed on every page. Does including this file on every page request significantly slow down the site? Is there a way to load these functions only once per user session instead of on every page load?

PHP is a flexible and easy-to-use language, especially for web sites.  It is not, however, a solution to look to if you are after extreme performance.   Unless head.php is extremely large, loading it on every page load is not going to make a significant difference to the performance of the site - there will be much lower hanging fruit to target to speed the site up (like server optimizations and optimizations within your PHP code)

You can use the require_once function in PHP to ensure to include the functions only once.
Check the manual here:
require_once PHP Manual
There's no such thing as loading per session. You have to include them on every page that you need them to work.


Is there a way to load these functions only once per user session instead of on every page load?

The session is serialized and stored on disk between HTTP requests which are resolved by PHP (which is not the same thing as a page load). So while in theory it would be possible to serialize the PHP code, put that in the session, dump it to disk at the end of the request then load it again from the session on the next request, parse and compile the code, this would be PHENOMONALLY slower than invoking the PHP source code files on each request via include/require (due to caching in APZ/Zend and on the VFS). It would also use a LOT more memory.

I have a head.php file containing functions that are needed on every page.

That's not a very scalable solution. Splitting this up into multiple files aligned to specific functions has a performance cost but its tiny - and makes your code MUCH more manageable.
OTOH caching the output of PHP can have big benefits for performance. Especially if you can leverage client side caching.
